# ruby, rails, constants, resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, constants

I have a bunch of classes that are resque jobs and I just noticed I have a constant defined in each named RECEIVER which contains the email distribution list for the jobs results.

What is the default behavior in ruby/rails if I have a constant RECEIVER = "emails" and have it defined in multiple classes. Each class assigns the value of RECEIVER to an instance of the class upon initialization.

Just trying to think of the best way to refactor something like this. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets defined in each class separately.  The best way to refactor to prevent code duplication would be to use a `module`

```
module CommonMethods
   RECEIVER = "emails"
end
```

and then in your class:

```
class SomeClass
  include CommonMethods

  #do stuff
end
```

That way the email list is only defined in one place.

You could also define other methods in here that are common to all of your classes.

Comment: awesome thanks. I thought including a module only included the instance methods? this also include constants?

Comment: Yes.  You can access the constant with `SomeClass::RECIEVER` after the module has been included